# error in mysql syntax in vb.net

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, connection-string

I get this error, while I'm testing the code below:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[student](ID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, SCHOOL) VALUES ('333', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa')' at line 1
```

I just recycled the code that I used in manipulating ms sql database. So the syntax must be wrong. What might be the correct syntax for adding records into mysql database?
Here is my current code:

```
 idnum = TextBox1.Text
        lname = TextBox2.Text
        fname = TextBox3.Text
        skul = TextBox4.Text


        Using sqlcon As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=testing;Uid=root;Pwd=nitoryolai123$%^;")

            sqlcon.Open()
            Dim sqlcom As New MySqlCommand()
            sqlcom.Connection = sqlcon

            sqlcom.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [student](ID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, SCHOOL) VALUES (@ParameterID, @ParameterLastName, @ParameterFirstName, @ParameterSchool)"

            sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterID", TextBox1.Text)
            sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterLastName", TextBox2.Text)
            sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterFirstName", TextBox3.Text)
            sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterSchool", TextBox4.Text)

            sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using
```

Please help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the square brackets from the `student` table name, and adding a space between table name and column list: `[student] (ID,   ...`

Without your table schema definition I can't be 100% sure, but ParameterID appears to be an int, but you are passing as a string (i.e. value is wrapped in single quotes). Try converting `TextBox1.Text` to an `int` first (using `Try.Parse`)