# AddWithValue is not member of MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

What would be the problem with my code? I am having an error AddWithValue is not member of  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter

This is my code:

```
    Dim bn As String = ""
    Dim bottles As Integer = 0

    Dim SQLStatement As String = "UPDATE patient SET number_of_bottles = @bottles WHERE bednumber = @bednumber"

    Using cnn As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; database=patientinfo;user id=root;password=")
        Dim cmdn As New MySqlCommand(SQLStatement, cnn)
        cmdn.Parameters.AddWithValue("bottles", bottles)
        cmdn.Parameters.AddWithValue("bednumber", bn)
        cnn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End Using
```

I am new in VB.net as well as MySql. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks ! :)

Comment: What ADO.Net MySql Provider do you use? I used the connector for ado.net at http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/ and your code checked out. Perhaps you could show us a screenshot or give some more details, pls!

Comment: One little error occured in your code. You wrote cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() instead of cmdn.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: What version of the MySql library are you using? It could be that you are using an old version; @pilgerstorfer-franz points to the download location for the ADO.Net client download. I'm using 6.5.4 (latest version) and `Command.Parameters.AddWithValue` is a supported method...

Comment: I just re-checked the tutorial and @LarsTech is perfectly right. You have to use @ with any parameters. So change your code to cmdn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bottles", bottles). Did you try changing your bn var to an existing value?

Comment: Just a note, I've always had to use ? instead of @ with the MySql provider.  It used to be very particular about that unless it's changed which is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the name you used in the parameter (the `@` sign is missing):

```
cmdn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bottles", bottles)
cmdn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bednumber", bn)
```

Comment: it doesnt solved my problem but i know it should not be like that reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907146/vb-mysql-addwithvalue-doesnt-pass-the-value-successfully

Comment: @CatherineTakishima bn looks like it should be a number, not a string.  What is bednumber in your table, string or int?  See [error in mysql syntax in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2440939/719186)

Comment: @CatherineTakishima Also, if the @ is the issue (I don't use MySQL very often), try using a differnt name than bednumber since your table has that name already.

Comment: I used Parameter.Add(parametername, value) I hope it is similar with Parameter.AddWithValue

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a provider that doesn't support "AddWithValue" (and some don't), you can make your own with extension methods.  Here is an example of an "AddWithValue" extension method with a few overloads (that extends IDbCommand).

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Adds a parameter into the IDbCommand and sets it's name, value and type.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="cmd"></param>
    ''' <param name="paramName"></param>
    ''' <param name="paramValue"></param>
    ''' <param name="dbType"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub AddWithValue(ByVal cmd As IDbCommand, ByVal paramName As String, ByVal paramValue As Object, ByVal dbType As DbType)
        Dim param As DbParameter = cmd.CreateParameter
        param.ParameterName = paramName
        param.DbType = dbType
        param.Value = paramValue
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Adds a parameter into the IDbCommand and name and value.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="cmd"></param>
    ''' <param name="paramName"></param>
    ''' <param name="paramValue"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub AddWithValue(ByVal cmd As IDbCommand, ByVal paramName As String, ByVal paramValue As Object)
        Dim param As DbParameter = cmd.CreateParameter
        param.ParameterName = paramName
        param.Value = paramValue
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Adds a parameter into the IDbCommand and sets it's name, value and type.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="cmd"></param>
    ''' <param name="paramName"></param>
    ''' <param name="paramValue"></param>
    ''' <param name="dbType"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub AddWithValue(ByVal cmd As IDbCommand, ByVal paramName As String, ByVal paramValue As Object, ByVal dbType As DbType, ByVal size As Integer)
        Dim param As DbParameter = cmd.CreateParameter
        param.ParameterName = paramName
        param.DbType = dbType
        param.Value = paramValue
        param.Size = size
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param)
    End Sub
```